# Cross domain Websockets with one domain as the server and one as the client. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

Hey guys just a theoretical question. I have been using ratchet php websockets and have figured out that you can send cross domain requests between two different websites. I have successfully been able to pass POSTs and SESSION variables across domains when switching pages.

Now my problem is this. My current webhost isnt supporting websockets because its a shared webhost. I have managed to get a cloud with amazon web services and host a chatroom im building on there, as well as log into it from my original webhost.

But I'm working on a social network now and I dont want to pay through the roof for a VPS just to use the websocket feature. So I figured if I wanted to build it in the meantime, maybe host the websocket server on the external cloud.

If I were to say, have a javascript client on my shared hosting website, but hosted the websocket server on the external cloud, would it be possible to send websockets to and from the external cloud server with the chat client on my website? Do I have to do something special like I did with CORS to include headers and stuff?

The kind of things I want to do includes: Facebook style private instant messaging, comments and posts updated live, live notifications, newsfeed, etc.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can. See the link bellow : [WebSocket](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=999255)

Comment: cool. Been following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYpSG5d5IPk

Was hoping it would still work cross domain using that technology :)